# How to remove common rows in two dataframes in Pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn

I have two dataframes - `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 has row1,row2,row3,row4,row5
df2 has row2,row5
```

I want to have a new dataframe such that `df1-df2`. That is, the resultant dataframe should have rows as - `row1,row3,row4`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the two dataframes rowwise, followed by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove all the duplicated rows in them.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"], "B":[0,1,1,1], "C":["A","A","B","A"]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"], "B":[1,0,1,0], "C":["A","B","A","B"]})

In [2]: df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
     A  B  C
0  foo  0  A
1  foo  1  A
2  foo  1  B
3  bar  1  A
0  foo  1  A
1  bar  0  B
2  foo  1  A
3  bar  0  B

In [4]: df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
Out[4]: 
     A  B  C
0  foo  0  A
2  foo  1  B
3  bar  1  A
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `index.difference()` function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), index= ['row' + str(i) for i in range(1, 6)])
df1

        0             1
row1    0.249451    -0.107651
row2    1.295390    -1.773707
row3    -0.893647   -0.683306
row4    -1.090551   0.016833
row5    0.864612    0.369138

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 2), index= ['row' + str(i) for i in [2, 5]])
df2

        0           1
row2    0.549396    -0.675574
row5    1.348785    0.942216

df1.loc[df1.index.difference(df2.index), ]

        0           1
row1    0.249451    -0.107651
row3    -0.893647   -0.683306
row4    -1.090551   0.016833
```

Comment: Note that this does not compare the contents of the two dataframes, it simply compares the values of the indexes.

Answer (score 5):

### This is the best way to do it:

```
df = df1.drop_duplicates().merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), on=df2.columns.to_list(), 
                   how='left', indicator=True)
df.loc[df._merge=='left_only',df.columns!='_merge']
```

Note that drop duplicated is used to minimize the comparisons. It would work without them as well.

### Why this is the best way?

The best way is to compare the row contents themselves and not the index or one/two columns and same code can be used for other filters like 'both' and 'right_only' as well to achieve similar results. `index.difference` only works for unique index based comparisons

Answer (score -6):

For these kind of questions, see left join in pandas.

Comment: First it's a left _join_. Second you should answer the question. This belongs in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am new to SO.